# Inserted data isnt saved Qt

Tags: sql, qt

my problem is that I'm trying to save data into my database in my project. It's shown right after the action, but after I close the app and open it again, I can't find the data. 
Here's my code for inserting a new row:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButtonUlozit_clicked(){   QMessageBox::StandardButton reply=QMessageBox::question(this,"Ukladání","Přejete si data uložit?", QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
if (reply==QMessageBox::Yes) {QSqlQuery qrry;
if(ui->radioButtonWeb->isChecked()){

    QString kod = ui->kodLine->text();
    qDebug()<<kod;
    QString odkaz = ui->odkazLine->text();
    qDebug()<<odkaz;
    QString popis = ui->popisLine->text();
    qDebug()<<popis;
    QString jazyk = ui->jazykLine->text();
    qDebug()<<jazyk;
    qrry.prepare( "INSERT INTO web (kod_predmet, odkaz, popis, kod_jazyk) VALUES ('"+kod+"','"+odkaz+"','"+popis+"','"+jazyk+"');");//ulozit data do tabulky 'web'
}
else if (ui->radioButtonKniha->isChecked()){
    QString kod1 = ui->kodLine1->text();
    qDebug()<<kod1;
    QString isbn = ui->isbnLine->text();
    qDebug()<<isbn;
    QString autor = ui->autorLine->text();
    qDebug()<<autor;
    QString nazev = ui->nazevLine->text();
    qDebug()<<nazev;
    QString vydat = ui->vydatEdit->text();
    qDebug()<<vydat;
    QString jazyk = ui->jazykLine1->text();
    qDebug()<<jazyk;
    QString rok = ui->rokLine->text();
    qDebug()<<rok;
    QString insert = "INSERT INTO literatura (kod_predmet, ISBN, autor, nazev, rok, vydavatelstvi,kod_jazyk) VALUES ('"+kod1+"','"+isbn+"','"+autor+"','"+nazev+"','"+rok+"','"+vydat+"','"+jazyk+"');";//ulozit data do tabulky 'literatura'
}
if (qrry.exec()) {
    QMessageBox::information(this,tr("Ukladání"),tr("Uloženo"));
} else
{
    QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("error::"),tr("Chyba!"));
}}
else {
    QMessageBox::information(this,"Ukladání","Data nebyla uložena");
}
```

}

[Inserting the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5WiO.png)

[How the table looks right after the changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cSh2.png)

And after I close and re-open my project the row is missing.
Simplified code:

```
QSqlQuery qrry;
    QString kod = ui->kodLine->text();
    qDebug()<<kod;
    QString odkaz = ui->odkazLine->text();
    qDebug()<<odkaz;
    QString popis = ui->popisLine->text();
    qDebug()<<popis;
    QString jazyk = ui->jazykLine->text();
    qDebug()<<jazyk;
    qrry.prepare( "INSERT INTO web (kod_predmet, odkaz, popis, kod_jazyk) VALUES ('"+kod+"','"+odkaz+"','"+popis+"','"+jazyk+"');");//ulozit data do tabulky 'web'
    qrry.exec();
```

Here's the connection to my database in dbliteratura.h:

```
inline void dbliteratura(){
QString sqlfile = "../dbliteratura.sql";
QFile   f(sqlfile);
if (!f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(0, "IO Error", "Couldn't open file" + sqlfile + " for reading");
        exit(1);
    }

QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database();
if (!db.isOpen())
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(0, "Database Error", "Database is not open");
        exit(2);
    }

// je to divne, ale neni mozne zpracovat celou sql davku, jednotlive prikazy
// tedy musime oddelit (;) a zadavat postupne
QString sql;
QSqlQuery q;
char z;

db.transaction();
while ( f.getChar(&z) )
    {
        sql = z;
        while (f.getChar(&z) && (z != ';'))  sql.push_back(z);
        q.exec(sql);
    }
db.commit();}
```

And MainWindow.cpp:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow){
ui->setupUi(this);
this->setWindowTitle("DB Literatura");
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName(":memory:");
dbliteratura();
```

Comment: Is the `QString insert` under your `else if (ui->radioButtonKniha->isChecked())` intended? Because it won't prepare your query.

Comment: Side note and suggestion: you may want to look into [`QSqlQuery::addBindValue()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#addBindValue), [`QSqlQuery::bindValue()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#bindValue), or [`QString::arg()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg-14) instead of using string concatenation (since it's slightly untidy, IMO).

Comment: @TrebuchetMS no, just forgot to change it for .prepare, but it didn't work as well.

Comment: A large chunk of information seems to be left out. "_It's shown right after the action_" we can't reproduce this with the code provided. (And specifically _where_ is it shown?) Also what message box popped up? How were the checkboxes set out? Lots of head-scratching. Try to simplify your code to a simple insert on-click. See if it works.

Comment: I tried to simplify the code, that didn't help, so, I'm adding printscreens of the results.

Comment: Show us the simplified code. Anything shorter than what's currently shown will help (given that it's a [mcve] and reproduces the same problem).

Comment: @TrebuchetMS did it. :)

Comment: Are you connecting to a `QSqlDatabase` by the default connection name? If not, you'll need to specify the `QSqlDatabase` in the initialisation of your `QSqlQuery`.

Comment: @TrebuchetMS how do I exactly do that? Sorry, I've just never tried that..

Comment: So a couple things: (1) how are you connecting your database? (2) Have you tried calling [`QSqlDatabase::commit()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#commit) after executing your sql?

Comment: @TrebuchetMS I added the connection, but I can't do the commit. Sorry, Im really new in Qt.